# Creating TextViews with RadioButton/RadioGroup Behavior (Or Vice Versa)

Tags: android, xml, radio-button

I wanted a clickable TextView that changes color and holds it, that changes previously changed text back to default color. And of course I wanted some state to be changed when each TextView was "checked." Basically a TextView that acts like a RadioButton, or a RadioButton minus the button.

At first I tried to come at from the TextView angle. But it seems like using RadioButtons and adding text behavior is easier since RadioButtons extend TextView anyway.

So I have this color resource applied to each RadioButton:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#0000ff" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#0000ff" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#0000ff" />
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#0000ff" />
<item android:color="#ff00ff00" />
</selector>
```

That gets me the text behavior I want. Now I just need a way to hide the RadioButton itself. Ideally this would be in XML so I can just apply a style to various RadioButton, but I'm not going to turn my nose up at a RadioButton extension.

So, anybody know how to hide the RadioButton button itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `CheckedTextView`. It supports `checked` state.

**OR**

You can use `RadioButton` and set its button to `null`:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/selector"
    android:button="@null"
    android:paddingLeft="0dip"/>
```

Comment: CheckedTextView seems like it should work, but how do I get this to interact with the radiogroup?

Comment: FYI, if you are trying to do this type of thing in API 10 or less, you need to also include `android:background="@null"`.

Comment: This answer will help me a lot when I apply  FontAwesome Icons in Android Design, Thanks a Lot Vladimir.